# Как отобразить элемент из многомерного json?

Tags: javascript

Есть `json`. `nationality.display_name` возвращает мне значение "Абхазия", а вот до `possilbe_positions` не получается достучаться. В идеале хотелось бы взять все значения из под массива и объединить их в строку с разделителем `;`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "surname": "Иванов",
    "name": "Иван",
    "patronymic": "Иваныч",
    "birth_date": "2017-09-08",
    "age": 14,
    "passport": "211111",
    "birth_place": "Dagestan",
    "passport_issued_by": "MVD",
    "date_issue": "2017-09-08",
    "validate_period": "2017-09-08",
    "comment": "Comment",
    "tensure": "09.09.2017",
    "qualification": "asd",
    "treatment_date": "2017-09-08",
    "interview_date": "2017-09-08",
    "phone1": "12",
    "phone2": "123",
    "patent": true,
    "migration_card": true,
    "registration": true,
    "med_book": true,
    "stop_sheet": true,
    "bank_card": "5469-6000-5555-5655",
    "import_record": true,
    "sex": "0",
    "email": "1@mail.ru",
    "created_at": "2017-09-08T00:00:00.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-09-09T06:55:08.126Z",
    "nationality_id": 1,
    "emp_type_id": 1,
    "status_treatment_id": 1,
    "status_interview_id": 1,
    "etnicity_id": 1,
    "stop_sheet_status_id": 1,
    "avatar": {
      "url": null
    },
    "residence_document_id": 1,
    "manager_id": 1,
    "desired_region_id": 3,
    "patent_region_id": 1,
    "settlement_id": null,
    "status_treatment": {
      "id": 1,
      "display_name": "Первичное обращение",
      "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:19.043Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:19.043Z"
    },
    "status_interview": {
      "id": 1,
      "display_name": "Собеседование пройдено",
      "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:19.386Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:19.386Z"
    },
    "nationality": {
      "id": 1,
      "display_name": "Абхазия",
      "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:16.441Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:16.441Z"
    },
    "emp_type": {
      "id": 1,
      "display_name": "Постоянное трудоустройство",
      "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:18.800Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:18.800Z"
    },
    "possible_positions": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "display_name": "Швея",
        "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:17.883Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:17.883Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "display_name": "Программист",
        "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:17.964Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:17.964Z"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "display_name": "Завхоз",
        "created_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:18.053Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-09-08T06:50:18.053Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: `possible_positions[0].display_name`? Не?

Comment: нет............

Comment: у меня работает так. А что вообще нужно сделать?

Comment: по ходу это ошибка в либе которую я юзаю. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46138139/ag-grid-not-display-nested-json вот тут полное описание

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я сам новичок, попробую Вам помочь. На сколько я понимаю, в JS у вас должен получиться массив для вывода, на подобии:

```
var rowData = [
    {make: "Toyota", model: "Celica", price: 35000},
    {make: "Ford", model: "Mondeo", price: 32000},
    {make: "Porsche", model: "Boxter", price: 72000}
];
```

Похоже, что Вы вставляете в этот массив НЕ значение, а переменную possible_positions[0].display_name.

```
{
  headerName: "position", field: "possible_positions[0].display_name",
  width: 180, pinned: true
}
```

В одну строку можно преобразовать таким способом:

```
let names = possible_positions.map((item)=>item.display_name).join();
```